# Windows running Synergy 1.4.2 does not startup minimized

Tags: windows-7, boot, window, synergy

I recently updated my synergy software to version 1.4.2 on my Windows 7 machine, and am unable to find the option to force the program to start in my tray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe if you right click the program's icon, do properties... then go to shortcut... and under run, there's an option for normal window, maximized, minimized. Try minimized.

Otherwise you can download a program that sticks other programs into the tray.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running it as a service. Although I'm not sure that the service feature of synergy works that well on Windows 7

Comment: Hmm, it should work fine for win 7. I designed it to work well with both Vista and 7. What problems did you have?